# Can I load unsigned driver permanently in 64 windows

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, kernel-module

I am planning to get into windows driver development and start to learn windows wdk
But I know that windows blocks loading unsigned drivers and I have to purchase a digital certificate but it's too expensive for me and I won't be developing drivers that I'll distribute to customers now
I'll be only testing on my home computer
I knew that I could turn off the signature enforcement and restart but the problem is that I am not the only one who uses the computer and can't make the test mode on all the time , and need my driver to be running
So when I load the driver in test mode then restart and go back to default settings will the driver load again ? Or I'll have to be running in test mode all the time ?
I mean with loading it permanently that I don't need to boot in test mode every time I want my driver to be running but load it once and return back with the driver running
My current windows is 8.1 64 bit

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Windows will not let you load a driver unsigned without test mode enabled, in general. But if it's only for temporal, private use, why not just make a startup script which starts the driver (sc start drivername) if test mode is enabled?

Comment: as I said above the computer I'm currently using isn't private . it's shared between me and two other men and they won't agree to work in test mode

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a VM to this, thats how I does it. Enter the VM to TEST MODE and also you can attach WinDbg KD to the VM so you will be able to debug your driver. Without being able to debug your driver it will be very hard for you to write drivers and run them.

TESTMODE - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ff553484%28v=vs.96%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

VM Kernel Debugging - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/attaching-to-a-virtual-machine--kernel-mode-

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable integrity check - `bcdedit /set nointegritychecks on`